# Error Trying to get property of non-object en PHP

Tags: php, json, webservice

Estoy desarrollando un WS en PHP en el cual debería mostrar el valor del dolar, pero me está dando el error de trying to get property 'Salida' of non-object y el error trying to get property 'datoscotizaciones'of non-object.

El código es el siguiente:

```
<?php
$url = "https://cotizaciones.bcu.gub.uy/wscotizaciones/servlet/awsbcucotizaciones?wsdl";
$context = [
    "ssl" => [
    "verify_peer"      => FALSE,
    "verify_peer_name" => FALSE,
    'crypto_method'    => STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLS_CLIENT
    ]
];

$options = [
    'cache_wsdl'     => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
    'stream_context' => stream_context_create($context)
];

$params = [
    'Entrada' => [
        'Moneda'     => ['item' => 2222],
        'FechaDesde' => '2022-03-10',
        'FechaHasta' => '2022-03-10',
        'Grupo'      => 0       ]
];

$client = new SoapClient($url, $options);
$response = $client->Execute($params);
//var_dump("<pre>",$response);
$respuestaDecodificada=json_encode($response);
echo "\n\n";
var_dump($respuestaDecodificada);
$dolarMostrar=$respuestaDecodificada->Salida;
$dolarMostrar2=$dolarMostrar->datoscotizaciones;
$dolarMostrar3=$dolarMostrar2->datoscotizaciones.dato;
$dolarMostrar4=$dolarMostrar3->TCC;
echo "Valor del dolar: ".$dolarMostrar4;
?>
```

El JSON que devuelve es este

```
{"Salida":
{"respuestastatus":
    {"status":1,
    "codigoerror":0,
    "mensaje":""},
    "datoscotizaciones":
        {"datoscotizaciones.dato":
            {"Fecha":"2022-03-10",
            "Moneda":2222,
            "Nombre":"DOLAR USA",
            "CodigoISO":"USD",
            "Emisor":"ESTADOS UNIDOS",
            "TCC":42.604,
            "TCV":42.604,
            "ArbAct":1,
            "FormaArbitrar":1
            }
        }
}
}
```

Hace tiempo que estoy tratando de solucionarlo, pero no encuentro la solucion.
Agradezco que me puedan ayudar. Desde ya gracias!

Comment: Usa [`json_decode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php.)

Answer (score 0):

Veo que **response** ya es un objeto PHP, por lo tanto no necesita ejecutar conversiones **json**, y luego, debido a que la propiedad que buscas (**datoscotizaciones.dato**) esta con un punto, debes encerrarla entre llaves **{}** y **entrecomillada** para su acceso correcto.

Así pues, cambia todo esto:

```php
$respuestaDecodificada=json_encode($response);
echo "\n\n";
var_dump($respuestaDecodificada);
$dolarMostrar=$respuestaDecodificada->Salida;
$dolarMostrar2=$dolarMostrar->datoscotizaciones;
$dolarMostrar3=$dolarMostrar2->datoscotizaciones.dato;
$dolarMostrar4=$dolarMostrar3->TCC;
echo "Valor del dolar: ".$dolarMostrar4;
```

por esto:

```php
$dolarMostrar=$response->Salida->datoscotizaciones->{"datoscotizaciones.dato"}->TCC;
echo "Valor del dolar: ".$dolarMostrar;
```